# Input value return NAN after clicking an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the `id` of the post when I click on the `image` I have.

when I click on image, I want to get `id` of the post that is there inside a form.

I'm sending that `id` of the post in `Ajax` request but before that I want to have that `id`.

When I `click` on the `image` instead of getting  the `id` of the post but when I click on the image I get `NAN`.

Here is what I'm doing to have the `id` of the post.

`Image`

```
  <img src='uploads/avatars/uw.png' class="like" style="width:25px;height:25px;" alt=""
               >
```

Here is my `home.blade.php`

```
@foreach
      // id is actually post id 
     <input type="hidden" name="id" class="id" id = 'id' value="{{$post->id}}">

@endforeach
```

When the `image` is clicked the following code runs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 // here I've two click handlers like


 // first click handler
 $('something').on('click',function(){

     // here I've retrieved the `id` of post using this:
     var form = $(this).closest('form');  // this works fine for this handler but not for the second one i.e for image



  });

 // second click handler
// click handler for the image click
   $('.like').on('click',function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var form = $(this).closest('form');

       var id = parseInt(form.find('.id').val());
       var islike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null;

       alert(id);
       $.ajax({
                method:'POST',
                url:'like',
                data:{islike:islike,id:id, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'}

        })

            // call back function

            .done(function(){
                // change the page
        });

   });





});
```

I'm using the approach that I have already used to get the `id` of the post using(approach I've used in first `click` handler):

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');
var id = parseInt(form.find('.id').val());
```

`.like` whhere I've send the request, I've code something like the following:

```
 public function likePost(Request $request){


    $post_id     = $request['id']; // postId is being send from ajax function
    $islike = $request['islike'] ==='true';
    $update = false;

    $post = find($post_id); // find that post

    if(!$post){
        return null;
    }

    $user = Auth::user();
    // check if I already like thi post.
    $like = $user->likes()->where('post_id',$post_id)->first();

    if($like){
        $already_like = $like->like; // second like is the column name
        $update = true;
        // undo like , if I liked it and I click on like then UNDO liking
        if($already_like == $like){
            // undo like here
            $like->delete();
            return null;
        }
    }else{
        $like = new Like();
    }

    $like->like = $islike;
    $like->user_id = $user->id;
    $like->post_id = $post->id;

    if($update){
        $like->update();
    }else{
        $like->save();

    }

    return null;


}
```

But that is returning NAN , why is this happening?

Please help , Thanks

Comment: instead of creating a hidden  `input` box, it would likely be best to simply attach a `data` attribute to the `img` tag. a.e. `<img src="foo.jpg" data-id="{{$post->id}}" />` and then, on click, just pull it from the image element. a.e. `HTMLImageElement.dataset.id`

Comment: how can I then use id in `second` click handler ? @zfrisch

Comment: I will happily write an answer, but I do not know what `isLike` is supposed to be? I don't understand why you're searching  for the previous element, turning the result into a boolean, and then sending it in your request?

Comment: it says this `HTMLImageElement.dataset is undefined` in console.

Comment: Actually I'm doing the process of liking and disliking

Comment: `HTMLImageElement` is the prototype of every image element. It was an example, but instead of `HTMLImageElement` you would point to the image element itself.

Comment: what should I write to grab that  `data = {{$post->id}}` @zfrisch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer:

*Adjustments to your `blade` file.*

You can include the post `id` as an attribute on the `img` element itself:

```
@foreach

  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="id" id = 'id' value="{{$post->id}}">
  <img src='uploads/avatars/uw.png' class="like" style="width:25px;height:25px;" alt="" data-id="{{$post->id}}" />

@endforeach
```

---

### Using Data Attributes

**Vanilla JS**:

When you have a `data` attribute set on an element you can access it through the `dataset` object on that element. In this particular case you can use it like this:

```
img.dataset.id; // data-id="whatever";
```

But the `dataset` object can store all sorts of information and they can all be applied to an element through attributes declared on the element using `data-identifier`. Here are some other examples:

```
element.dataset.number; // data-number=5
element.dataset.group; // data-group="some group guid"
```

**JQuery**

In `JQuery` you can access data even easier by using a provided `.data` method. This can be used like this:

```
$(image).data("id");
```

in line with the other examples:

```
$(element).data("number"); // data-number=5
$(element).data("group"); // data-group="some group guid"
```

---

### Adjusting your code:

We only need to adjust your second handler it sounds like, and instead of searching for an `element` you can simply use `$(this)` because the event is being called on the `image` with the class `.like`.

Because you apply it as a string in your `blade` file, you still need to use `parseInt`, but you can rewrite the `id` declaration as:

```
var id = parseInt( $( this ).data( "id" ) );
```

The rest, I believe, can remain the same.

---

### Example Code:

```
// click handler for the image click
$( '.like' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();


  var id = parseInt( $( this ).data( "id" ) );
  var islike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null;

  $.ajax( {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'like',
    data: {
      islike: islike,
      id: id,
      _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
    }

  } )
} );
```

Comment: @contributor let me know if there's something I misunderstood. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is working but it I think it leads to some another error.
In response of ajax call I get `internal server error`, why is this so ? @zfrisch

Comment: I get the `id` of the post then I send it to `/like` where I've some code to deal with that .
please have a look at the updated post, I'm gonna update it in a second

Comment: please have a look at the updated post, and see what is going wrong that it is giving `internal server error` @zfrisch

Comment: @contributor I'll take a look sometime in the next 12 hours, but if you're getting an internal server error it's likely something outside of your code that's causing it.

Comment: Okay fine, I'll try to solve it, but please do have a look at the url `like` where I'm sending request, if you want to have a look at whole code, I'm happy to share that with you also @zfrisch

Comment: thanks for your help, I solve that problem that was due to something else, however the question I asked solved my relevant problem.
Thank You dear @zfrisch